# Best method of scaling text to fill an HTML5 canvas

Tags: text, html, canvas, svg, scale

I need to 'scale' text to fill an antire HTML5 canvas. It appears that the `scale()` method does not affect text. I've seen approximation methods with iterative loops on the `measureText()` method but this doesn't get me exactly what I need. Ideally I'd like to fill both horizontally and vertically without conserving the aspect ratio. Would SVG possibly be able to help with this?

Comment: So, in case you have five characters and a canvas with a width of 19 pixels, you want your text to fill the entire canvas (not only 15px)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad - Scale DOES apply to text. I've come up with a solution:

```
context.font = "20px 'Segoe UI'";
var metrics = context.measureText("Testing!");
var textWidth = metrics.width;

var scalex = (canvas.width / textWidth);
var scaley = (canvas.height / 23);

var ypos = (canvas.height / (scaley * 1.25));

context.scale(scalex, scaley);
context.fillText("Testing!", 0, ypos);
```

Comment: If you're running this in a loop, remember to `context.save()` before transformations, and `context.restore()` after (preferably in a finally block).

Answer (score 1):

Scale does affect text. Try this:

```
var can = document.getElementById('test');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillText("test", 10, 10); // not scaled text


ctx.scale(3,3);
ctx.fillText("test", 10, 10); // scaled text
```

See it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3zeBk/8/